# Share ARWorldMap to multiple devices by storing on Backend server

Tags: swift, arkit

I want to map certain spots and store the mapping on backend server so that whenever other devices are on that spot location, the users can localize that spot and AR content is displayed accordingly. I extracted the ARWorldMap and store the archived data in a file and upload it on a server. I then downloaded the file on another device and unarchived the data to ARWorldMap and retrieved the object successfully. But when I assign this map to initialWorldMap of ARSessionConfiguration, the World tracking fails to initialize.

Can someone guide me if I'm doing anything wrong or what's the best way to achieve my requirements/use case.

Comment: post the code where you restore the position.